# What has happened to the UCN5804?

Tags: stepper-motor

I know this is like my other question on the SAA1027 but i can't find the UCN5804 anywhere. Are they obsolete now?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From http://www.allegromicro.com/en/Products/Part_Numbers/Archive/index.asp:

> 5804: BiMOS II Unipolar Stepper-Motor
>   Translator/Driver
>
> http://www.allegromicro.com/en/Products/Part_Numbers/Archive/5804.pdf
>
> discontinued October 2004; replaced by
>   A3967 and A3977